# How can i use generic in an implicit operator?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I have a c++ class that is very simple:

```
struct Pt_t
{
    T x, y;
    template <class T2> operator Pt_t<T2>() { Pt_t<T2> pt = {x, y}; return pt; }
};
```

That allows me to create a pt that has T as any type I want. I can also do `Pt_t<s8> = Pt_t<u64>;` without a problem. How do I do the same in C#? I tried the below and got an error:

```
    class Pt<T>
    {
        public T x, y;
        //between operator and <T2>, error CS1031: Type expected
        public static implicit operator<T2> Pt<T>(Pt<T2> v) {
            Pt<T> r = new Pt<T>();
            r.x = v.x;
            r.y = v.y;
            return r; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, "Pt_t" isn't an operator symbol in C++... what was it you tried to write before it got mangled (in C++ as well as C#)?

Comment: @Pontus - it is attempting to be a conversion operator... to Pt with a different generic type argument

Comment: Ah: a class name -- should have read more carefully!

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think that is possible. You may have to add a method, such as `To<T>`.

The next problem will be "how to get from `T2` to `T` - you can't just assign them. One option might be a conversion delegate:

```
public Pt<TDestination> To<TDestination>(
    Converter<T, TDestination> converter)
{
    if (converter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");
    Pt<TDestination> t = new Pt<TDestination>();
    t.x = converter(x);
    t.y = converter(y);
    return t;
}
...
var p = new Pt<int> { x = 1, y = 2 };
var p2 = p.To(t => t.ToString()); // a Pt<string>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I can see where to go from here. (.toShort, toUshort, all using a simple one line Converter<> or the user To(OwnConv);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nemerle: ( http://github.com/rsdn/nemerle ) :

```
using System.Console;

class A[T]
{
    public static @:[From](x : A[From]) : A[T]
    {
      A()
    }
}


class Base{}
class Derived{}


def a = A.[Derived]();
def b : A[Base] = a;

WriteLine($"$a $b");
```

---

Output:

```
A`1[Derived] A`1[Base]
```

Reflector for code:

```
internal class A<T>
{
    public static implicit operator A<T><From>(A<From> x)
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}

public class a
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A<Derived> a = new A<Derived>();
        A<Base> a2 = (A<Base>) a;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a) + " " + Convert.ToString(a2));
    }
}
```